# org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepositoryclass file for org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Whenever i extend `JpaRepository` in any interface, like below

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

I get this error

```
java: cannot access org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository
  class file for org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository not found
```

Comment: Sounds like `spring-data-commons` isn't in your classpath… did you check?

Comment: @slauth, do you mean in the pom.xml file ?

Comment: If you're using Maven then yes ;) Have a look at what `mvn dependency:tree` outputs.

Comment: mvn dependency:tree ...downloaded some files but the error persisted.

Comment: [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jdbc:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-relational:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.5.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.32:compile

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` doesn't change anything… it is used to show the effective dependencies of a project. Verify that `spring-data-commons` is included in the output.

Comment: sure, it's included.

Comment: This looks strange… you have mixed versions 2.2.4 and 2.5.4 in your classpath; also you should depend on `spring-data-jpa` instead of `spring-data-jdbc`. See [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.5.4&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=data-jpa) for a correct setup.

Comment: I had added both spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc dependencies in the pom.xml file. have removed spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc.

Comment: actually any projected cloned from git hub using jpa, i get the same error. i did delete all the files of sring data and reinstalled, but i still get the same error. i am using java 11

Answer (score 0):

Adding the dependencies below solved my problem.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```